# Actual function which saves the product details to table and which object does the task?

Tags: magento2

1. **Which** is the actual **function** which saves all the product details on Clicking on **Import** button during csv import?
2. **Where** is the actual **saving** of any particular column that is happening in that function, like where exactly is the column say for eg: `sku`, `attribute_set_code`, `product_type`, `categories` etc gets **saved**?
3. Is the `_saveProducts()` under `CatalogImportExport` Model Product
   the right function?
4. If so, which object is saving all the details in the table?

Answer (score 2):

The import calls the method `\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::_importData`.
Depending on your selection (delete, replace, merge) it calls either `_deleteProducts` or `_replaceProducts` or `_saveProductsData`.
For the replace and merge behavior, the `_saveProducts` method is called.
This method takes each batch of products data to import, validates each row.
Then it does a mapping between the file columns and the attributes and when everything is computed it calls the method `saveProductEntity`.
This method just inserts the needed values in the `catalog_product_entity` table (sku, created_at).
Then it calls `_saveProductWebsites` that inserts the associations between products and websits into `catalog_product_website` table.
Then it does the same for category ids in `catalog_product_category` via 
`_saveProductCategories`, then tier prices via `_saveProductTierPrices`, then images via `_saveMediaGallery` and at the end the product attributes via `_saveProductAttributes`.
I think this is the method you are looking for.
This methods checks the table where the attribute value goes (`catalog_product_entity_int`, or `_varchar` or `_text`, or `_datetime` or `_decimal`) and inserts the value corresponding to the attribute id and store id.

Comment: Marius, thanks for the explanation, just want to know how we can replicate the same function for saving the "entity_id" also for the replace and merge behavior to a serperate custom table(not catalog_product_entity )

Comment: Is it possible to resuse the model collection class already defined to CatalogImportExport as explained here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128590/reuse-the-model-collection-for-saving-values-to-database-in-other-class

Comment: in the `saveProductEntity` method there is this line `$entityTable = $this->_resourceFactory->create()->getEntityTable();`. replace in your  cloned code this with the value you need.

Comment: _resourceFactory->create()->getTable('My_Table'); or _resourceFactory->create()->getEntityTable()  , how is the format used for getEntityTable() if its for catalog_product_entity?

Comment: just make `$entityTable = 'your_table_name_here'` for now to see if it works.

Comment: Marius, i tried like if (!$entityTable) {
            $entityTable = 'tgs_queue';   
        }    i get Additional data: Notice: Use of undefined constant entityTable - assumed 'entityTable' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_3\app\code\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product.php on line 1314

Comment: Im using this way:  $this->_resourceFactory->create()->getTable('tgs_queue');  But how to save my column values to custom table